# Why are there so many JavaScript errors on SO itself?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, javascript

I'm using IE8. I noticed a lot of errors popping up whenever I visit Stack Overflow.

> master.js  line: 1
>
> 'jQuery' is underfined question.js
>   Line: 1
>
> Object expected ask Line: 25
>
> '$' is undefined global-login.js Line:
>   154
>
> Object expected ask Line: 141
>
> Object expected ask Line: 149
>
> 'jQuery' is undefined tageditor.js
>   Line: 1
>
> Object expected ask Line: 177
>
> 'jQuery' is undefined
>   jquery.typewatch.js Line: 14
>
> Object expected ask Line: 197
>
> Object expected ask Line: 278 code: 0
>   URl:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: should this be in meta?

Comment: "I'm using IE" well there's your issue right there, sorry very catty no offence meant

Comment: @awoodland: Certainly.

Answer (score 5):

There aren't any errors at the moment.  *You're* experiencing errors, that's a clear distinction...and (IMO) an assumption you should go with until others report trouble.

You're either blocking some scripts from loading...or can't reach google's CDN that jQuery is being included from.  Make sure you can reach: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 2):

These errors are not normal. It sounds like jquery.js is failing to load. Since most of the site's client-side scripting is dependent on it, that's going to leave you with a lot of errors and broken functionality.

SO gets its copy of jQuery from `ajax.googleapis.com`. Can you access that site? Is it being blocked, at your machine or upstream?